# Need help implementing a Full Outer Join in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, outer-join

I'm having trouble getting a query to work properly in Access. I need a full outer join on dbo_cardpurchases and dbo_vendors so that all all vendors will appear in the query regardless of whether a purchase was made at that vendor. But Access doesn't support full outer joins. How else can I do this?

```
SELECT dbo_vendors.name, 
       Iif([fundingsourceid] = 10, [amount], "")        AS Credit, 
       Iif(( [fundingsourceid] = 2 ) 
            OR ( [fundingsourceid] = 3 ), [amount], "") AS EBT, 
       Iif([fundingsourceid] = 4, [amount], "")         AS [Match], 
       dbo_cardpurchases.updateddate, 
       dbo_markets.marketid 
FROM   (((dbo_cardpurchases 
          LEFT JOIN dbo_vendors 
                 ON dbo_cardpurchases.vendorid = dbo_vendors.vendorid) 
         LEFT JOIN dbo_cardfundings 
                ON dbo_cardpurchases.cardfundingid = 
                   dbo_cardfundings.cardfundingid) 
        INNER JOIN dbo_marketevents 
                ON dbo_cardpurchases.marketeventid = 
                   dbo_marketevents.marketeventid) 
       INNER JOIN dbo_markets 
               ON dbo_marketevents.marketid = dbo_markets.marketid 
ORDER  BY dbo_vendors.name;
```

Comment: Just to confirm: These tables are Access linked tables connected to SQL Server tables, correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the Wikipedia article on joins [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join), for sample tables

[employee]

```
LastName    DepartmentID
----------  ------------
Heisenberg            33
Jones                 33
Rafferty              31
Robinson              34
Smith                 34
Williams            NULL
```

and [department]

```
DepartmentID  DepartmentName
------------  --------------
          31  Sales         
          33  Engineering   
          34  Clerical      
          35  Marketing
```

the full outer join

```sql
SELECT *
FROM employee FULL OUTER JOIN department
    ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID;
```

can be emulated using a UNION ALL of three SELECT statements. So, in Access you could do

```sql
SELECT dbo_employee.LastName, dbo_employee.DepartmentID,
       dbo_department.DepartmentName, dbo_department.DepartmentID
FROM dbo_employee
INNER JOIN dbo_department ON dbo_employee.DepartmentID = dbo_department.DepartmentID

UNION ALL

SELECT dbo_employee.LastName, dbo_employee.DepartmentID,
       NULL, NULL
FROM dbo_employee
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo_department
             WHERE dbo_employee.DepartmentID = dbo_department.DepartmentID)

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, NULL,
       dbo_department.DepartmentName, dbo_department.DepartmentID
FROM dbo_department
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM dbo_employee
             WHERE dbo_employee.DepartmentID = dbo_department.DepartmentID)
```

However, since you are using linked tables into SQL Server you can just use an Access pass-through query and perform a "real" FULL OUTER JOIN using T-SQL:

[image: ptq_foj.png]

Pass-through queries always produce recordsets that are not updateable, but a native Access query against linked tables that uses UNION ALL is going to produce a recordset that is not updatable anyway, so why not take advantage of the speed and simplicity of just using SQL Server to run the query?

Comment: Well that makes things 10x easier! (pass-throughs) Thanks. To my surprise the outer join didn't have the effect I was looking for though.