# MS Access - check-in/check-out system

Tags: ms-access

I have an issue writing a query in MS Access that would pull information from two tables.
Quick description:
Employees start the job and click the button in Excel macro. The macro saves the date and a comment that the employee provides (not required). Next, the macro pushes the information into a table in Access database which gathers all 'check-ins' of all employees. There's a possibility for a person to check-in twice by accident. This is an example how the table would look like after two work days, in a company with three employees:
[check-in table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ugat.png)

Similarly, the macro lets a user to check-out, also with optional comment:
[check-out table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMzkM.png)

What I need is a query that would consolidate two of these tables and show check-in/check-out of employees for a previous day, together with provided comment. So the result of the query would look like this:
[outcome of a table for previous day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P46DD.png)
Column order is absolutely irrelevant here

```
SELECT min(checkin.[check-in time]), max(checkout.[check-out time]), checkin.[comment] AS [check-in comment], checkout.[comment] AS [check-out comment] 
FROM checkin 
RIGHT JOIN chekout ON checkin.analyst = checkout.analyst
    WHERE checkin[check-in time] = Date()-3;
```

Bad thing is, MS Access throws:

> Syntax error in JOIN operation

Could anyone help me out and advise how should I proceed? Unfortunately I have no control how the system was implemented (Macro in Excel connected with Access) and sadly I have not much experience in MS Access.

EDIT:
Thank you very much @Erik, much appreciated. It helped a lot and I'll be more diligent next time when it comes to typos. The new problem presented itself however. It is possible for a person to check-in, without checking-out and vice versa. Lets say there's another row in the first table -> Meg015 checked in at 7:20 on 08.06.2018 but forgot to check out:

[see an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMzgc.png)

I would like MS Access to present this information accordingly (without forgotten check-out time):
[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdrQA.png)

Since there's no Full Outer Join in MS Access, I was thinking about following UNION/LEFT and RIGHT JOINs:

```
SELECT checkin.analyst, min(checkin.[check-in time]), max(checkout.[check-out time]), checkin.comment, checkout.comment
FROM checkin RIGHT JOIN checkout ON (checkin.analyst = checkout.analyst OR checkout.analyst = NULL OR checkin.analyst = NULL)
WHERE (format(checkin.[check-in time], "Short Date") = format(checkout.[check-out time], "Short Date") OR checkout.[check-out time] = NULL) AND format(checkin.[check-in time], "Short Date") = date()-3
GROUP BY checkin.analyst, checkin.comment, checkout.comment

UNION 

SELECT checkout.analyst, min(checkin.[check-in time]), max(checkout.[check-out time]), checkin.comment, checkout.comment
FROM checkin LEFT JOIN checkout ON (checkin.analyst = checkout.analyst OR checkin.analyst = NULL OR checkout.analyst = NULL)
WHERE (format(checkin.[check-in time], "Short Date") = format(checkout.[check-out time], "Short Date") OR checkin.[check-in time] = NULL) AND format(checkin.[check-in time], "Short Date") = date()-3
GROUP BY checkout.analyst, checkin.comment, checkout.comment;
```

Sadly, Meg's check-in details are not visible in a result of the query above. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Oh, and for your deleted comment, view [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26512667/7296893), which is the nicest way to implement a full outer join imo. You can use one `LEFT JOIN` and do it only with one `UNION ALL`, though.

Comment: Ay, I'm looking through it right now - thanks again @Erik. I've deleted comment 'cause I posted it by accident. I've decide to just edit the main post instead due to character limitation.

Comment: `format(checkin.[check-in time], "Short Date") = date()-3` is an exceptionally bad idea. Don't use format to compare dates. Use `DateDiff`, like I showed in my answer. Using `Format` is both way slower, and might cause errors depending on your locale. Also, use `IS NULL` when testing if fields are `Null`. `Null = Null` results in `Null` instead of `True`, which gets cast to `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dot, have misspelt checkout in your join, and are using aggregates without grouping by the other columns.

Also, you're testing if a date is equal to a date with time, which will pretty much always be false.

Anyway, this is how your query should look like:

```
SELECT checkout.analyst, min(checkin.[check-in time]), max(checkout.[check-out time]), checkin.[comment] AS [check-in comment], checkout.[comment] AS [check-out comment] 
FROM checkin 
RIGHT JOIN checkout ON checkin.analyst = checkout.analyst
WHERE DATEDIFF('d',checkin.[check-in time],  Date()) = 3
GROUP BY checkout.analyst, checkout.[comment], checkin.[comment]
```

(Do note that questions with this many errors can get closed as too broad).